# How to make a button in a Scratch that takes you to some website?,

Tags: javascript, mit-scratch

I know that this won't work in a normal Scratch. Maximum with Turbowarp, but there is one problem. Turbowarp makes JavaScript out of Scratch, and unfortunately I don't know this language. What should I do, or what command should I enter, so that the button takes me to the site?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

TurboWarp has an [extension](https://extensions.turbowarp.org/) called [Network](https://extensions.turbowarp.org/true-fantom/network.js) that offers you (among others) the following blocks:

- open (...) in new tab
- open (...) in new window
- redirect this tab to (...)

Quick link to try it out:
https://turbowarp.org/editor?extension=https://extensions.turbowarp.org/true-fantom/network.js

Example:

[image: Screenshot of TurboWarp with Network extension]

When executed, the blocks will always ask permission before proceeding.

[image: Screenshot of security warning]

Answer (score 0):

A method is making a cloud variable in turbowarp called **Open link** and activate **Special cloud behaviors** in the packager. When the value of **Open link** is set to an url, the project will attempt to open a new tab with that url open. It isn't always reliable due to the popup blockers built in most browsers.

[image: Cloud variables in the packager]

The full doc on special cloud behaviors is [here](https://docs.turbowarp.org/packager/special-cloud-behaviors) or you can access it through the interrogation that appears on the side of the tick box on the packager:

[image: Special cloud behaviors image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a button for that, but you can add the link to a list, and then have it appear when a button is pressed. Because text can be copied from lists (if you are the creator of the project or not) you can copy the link and then open a new tab. But use it responsibly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35084540)